# How to ignore parent tag while unmarshalling to Object

Tags: parent, unmarshalling

For the below Xml, while unmarshalling to an object, "OperatingHours" tag needs to be ignored, such that only hours tags will be considered for unmarshall.

```
<Location locale="en-US">
     <TelephoneNumber>
          <FunctionalTypeDescription>xxx</FunctionalTypeDescription> 
          <PhoneNumber>00000</PhoneNumber> 
     </TelephoneNumber>
     <OperatingHours>
          <Hours>
              <ShortName>xxx</ShortName> 
              <FullName>aaaa</FullName> 
          </Hours>
          <Hours>
               <ShortName>yyy</ShortName> 
               <FullName>bbb</FullName> 
          </Hours>
     </OperatingHours>
```

I have my Object as follows :

```
   Class AAA {

     private List<TelephoneNumber> phnums;
     private List<Hours> hours;
}
```

I don't want to create a separate class called "OperatingHours" for wrapping the hours object. In simple please XML should be as follows. 
Any help highly appreciated. Thanks

```
  <Location locale="en-US">
       <TelephoneNumber>
            <FunctionalTypeDescription>xxx</FunctionalTypeDescription> 
           <PhoneNumber>00000</PhoneNumber> 
       </TelephoneNumber>
       <Hours>
          <ShortName>xxx</ShortName> 
         <FullName>aaaa</FullName> 
       </Hours>
      <Hours>
          <ShortName>yyy</ShortName> 
          <FullName>bbb</FullName> 
      </Hours>
  </Location>
```

Comment: is it for C# language?

Comment: Add some relevant tag with the question